# using sublime 3 SFTP on Amazon EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, sublimetext3, sftp

I already created an instance of EC2 and the instance state is running. 
I am able to ssh to my instance with Cygwin64 at my Windows 7.

but when I am trying to SFTP to my instance with sublime 3:

```
Connecting to SFTP server "ubuntu@xxx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com" as "eric" ...... failure (Connection timeout)
```

Here's the config.json:

```
{
"type": "sftp",

"sync_down_on_open": true,

"host": "ubuntu@xxx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com",
"user": "eric",

"remote_path": "/home/Eric",
"connect_timeout": 30,

//"ssh_key_file": "C:/cygwin64/home/Eric/.ssh/aws-key.pem",
"ftp_flags": ["-o IdentityFile=C:/cygwin64/home/Eric/.ssh/aws-key.pem"],

}
```

does `ssh_keyfile:` and  `ftp_flags` matter for Windows 7?

Answer (score 3):

1. Install sftp in Sublime

[image]

2. Convert your aws pem key file to ppk key file by using puttygen.

[image]

3. Config sftp
   Click File->SFTP/FTP->Setup Server to write below json into the file.
   If you use aws linux distribution, your username will NOT be 'ubuntu'.

[image]

4. Connect to EC2

Click File->SFTP/FTP->Browse Server, to select your json file in Step 3.

Answer (score 1):

"Connection timeout" is a pretty straightforward error. Your computer is sending a connection request to a remote address and port, and you're not getting a response from the remote system.

There are essentially two things that could cause this:

1. Your connection attempts are being blocked by a firewall somewhere.
2. The remote system is down (turned off), or it's not connected to the network, or the address isn't assigned to a computer.

If you can connect to the remote system using one program, but you get a connection timeout from a different program (on the same computer, connected to the same network), then my first guess would be that the two programs aren't actually trying to connect to the same remote system. You could have misspelled the remote hostname or IP address, for example.

Answer (score 1):

I found it myself. Becuase the SFTP plugin using PSFTP.exe, It doesn't work with .pem, we need to convert it to .ppk, I used PuTTy's Putty Key Generator to do it.